# Simple expand collapse using jquery plus minus (font awesome) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Iam working on expand collapse using jquery I have code i have put alerts to check where i am did mistake on my code it was not working till state true i am getting alerts but after that i am not alert also.

Here is my jquery code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".expand").click(function() {
    var state = $(this).children("div").hasClass("minus");
    alert("state" + state);
    if (state == true) {
        $(this).children("div").removeClass("plus").addClass("minus");
    } else {
        $(this).children("div").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
    }
    //$(this).parents(".header").next(".body").slideToggle(-100).toggleClass("toggle");
    var state = $(this).parents(".header").next(".body").hasClass("toggle");
});
});
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/0072wxdg/1/)

I have searched in stackoverflow there are so many suggestion on expand collapse  but I want to know what i am doing wrong here kindly please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$(".expand").click(function() {
        var state = $(this).children("div").hasClass("minus");
       alert( state);
        if (state == true) {

            $(this).children("div").addClass("plus"); //changed this
            $(this).children("div").removeClass("minus"); //changed this
        } else {

            $(this).children("div").removeClass("plus"); //changed this
             $(this).children("div").addClass("minus"); //changed this
        }
        //$(this).parents(".header").next(".body").slideToggle(-100).toggleClass("toggle");
        var state = $(this).parents(".header").next(".body").hasClass("toggle");
    });
   });
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/0072wxdg/2/)**

**Updated**

```
 $(this).parents(".header").next("#collapse").toggleClass("body");
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/0072wxdg/3/)**

Comment: thanks for your effort but expand collpase is not happening

Comment: with the updated code inside content is not toggle but 

you have put $(this).parents(".header").next(".body").slideToggle(-100).toggleClass("toggle"); this is working now

Comment: sorry I am facing still issue :(

Comment: Use this  $(this).parents(".header").next("#collapse").slideToggle(-100).toggleClass("body");

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/0072wxdg/4/ dont use next(".body") use next("#collapse")

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution for my question

```
$(".expand").click(function() {
            var state = $(this).children("div").hasClass("minus");
         // alert( state);
            if (state == true) {

                $(this).children("div").addClass("plus");
                $(this).children("div").removeClass("minus");
            } else {

                $(this).children("div").removeClass("plus");
                 $(this).children("div").addClass("minus");
            }
            //alert(state);
             $(this).parents(".header").next("#collapse").toggle();
            //var state = $(this).parents(".header").next(".body").hasClass("toggle");
        });
```